# How to put diffrent values depending on the item clicked in the recyclerview

Tags: java, android

when I click on each item of the recyclerview I want to go to another activity but the values in the activity will be different depending on the item clicked in the recyclerview.

For example : If I have a list of TV shows and when I click on each item it will go to the same activity and show me different episodes list.

Anyone can help how to achieve this?

Comment: use putExtra() in Intent object when you start activity, and in your next activity, get the intent and use getExtra() to get the information about which TV show the user clicked on

Comment: can you post your recyclerView adapter class?

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio provides you with various project templates when creating a new project, If you have a look at the one described as `Master/Detail Flow`.

[image: Project Template Window]

This will give you some working code that should cover your use case, which when comfortable that you understand it, you can then begin to implement into your own project.

Comment: Unsure as to why this has been downvoted. A comment would've been helpful.